# How to use golang 1.7 context with http.Request (for Authentication)

Tags: go

I have an `IsAuthenticated` function to check if the request is authenticated (checking the JWT in the `Authorization` header)

```
func IsAuthenticated(a *framework.AppContext, r *http.Request) (int, error) {
  // ... do authentication. user is authenticated User object
  ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "user", user)
  r = r.WithContext(ctx) 
  return 200, nil
}
```

I find that it appears that `r = r.WithContext(ctx)` does not override the request object? How should I implement this? Do I need to requrn a request instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not clear to me exactly how what you show is a "middleware", or how it is being executed. Since you are only changing your local variable `r`, and never giving that to anyone else, there is no way your change wil be visible outside your function.

There have been a variety of middleware flavors in the go landscape, but since go 1.7 I have seen a lot more moving towards middleware functions of the form:

```
func IsAuthenticated(next http.Handler) http.Handler{
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
       //authenticate. Set cookies.
       //403 if not authenticated, etc.
       ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "user",u)
       next(w,r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}
```

This can be used to chain handlers together like so:

```
http.Handle("/foo/bar", IsAuthenticated(myHandler))
```

(or use something like [alice](https://github.com/justinas/alice) to make chaining middlewares even easier.)

This way, when `myHandler` gets invoked, it will have the new request created by `IsAuthenticated`, and it can fetch the user with something like:

`user := r.Context().Get("user").(*User)`

Comment: yeah, then you will probably need to return r and pass it down the request chain, or else return the user, and have the middleware actually set it on the context.

Comment: What I thought was that since request was passed by reference, it will be changed?

Comment: `*r = r.WithContext...` or something similar might do that. I'm not super confident if that would or would not screw other things up though.

Comment: In regards to `*r = r.WithContext`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825733/how-to-set-context-value-inside-http-handlefunc