# How to set context value inside http.HandleFunc?

Tags: go

I want to set a context value inside an http.HandleFunc. The following approach seems to work.

I'm a little worried about `*r = *r.WithContext(ctx)` though.

```
type contextKey string
var myContext = contextKey("myContext")

func setValue(r *http.Request, val string)  {
  ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), myContext, val)
  *r = *r.WithContext(ctx)
}

http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    setValue(r, "foobar")
})
```

What's the best approach to set a context variable inside an http.HandleFunc?

Comment: Just ran into this issue for one of my projects. I solved it by using the BaseContext field in the server struct. By initializing the BaseContext with a custom context, enables the server to have this custom context for all incoming requests. Checkout the definition of the struct here: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/net/http/server.go;l=2611

Answer (score 5):

The code in the question overwrites the request object. This can result in code up the stack using the wrong context value. `Request.WithContext` creates a shallow copy of the request to avoid this. Return a pointer to that shallow copy.

```
func setValue(r *http.Request, val string) *http.Request {
  return r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), myContext, val))
}

http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r = setValue(r, "foobar")
})
```

If then handler invokes some other handler, then pass the new request along to the new handler:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r = setValue(r, "foobar")
    someOtherHandler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
})
```

Comment: This would make the new context only visible to the HandleFunc though? Meaning `myContext` key is not available for any handler downstream.

Comment: Pass the new request to the downstream handler instead of the original handler.  See edited answer.

Comment: But what is the setValue function? I don't have it available.

Comment: @Stefan The `setValue` function is declared on the first line of code in this answer.